# PayPal Error - Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm using JavaScript to submit the following form. It opens PayPal in a new page, but I get the "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later." error. I guess the real question, since I know the JavaScript is good and the HTML values and business email are good, is, is there anything wrong with the following paypal HTML format? Either PayPal itself has a site issue, which could be a reason to not use PayPal, or there is an issue with the code.

```
<form method='post' encytype='x-www-form-urlencoded' target='paypal' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>
  <input name='cmd' type='hidden' value='_cart' />
  <input name='business' type='hidden' value='this_part_is_good@somewhere.com' />
  <input name='currency_code' type='hidden' value='USD' />
  <input name='lc' type='hidden' value='US' />
  <input name='no_shipping' type='hidden' value='0' />
  <input name='item_name_1' type='hidden' value='correct value 1'>
  <input name='item_number_1' type='hidden' value='pid_59478d15575766.87101191' />
  <input name='amount_1' type='hidden' value='100.00' />
  <input name='item_name_2' type='hidden' value='correct value 2' />
  <input name='item_number_2' type='hidden' value='pid_59478d1557a0a8.85058626' />
  <input name='amount_2' type='hidden' value='30.00' />
  <input name='item_name_3' type='hidden' value='correct value 3' />
  <input name='item_number_3' type='hidden' value='pid_59478d1557cc26.16520690' />
  <input name='amount_3' type='hidden' value='30.00' />
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so - how long have you been trying this "code"

Comment: Just an hour or so.

Comment: `I'm using JavaScript to submit the following form` - can you share that code

Comment: That part works. It submits and opens PayPal in a new window.

Comment: right - except that it doesn't work **correctly**, you said so yourself, that's why I asked (seems a bit odd to submit a form where all the inputs are hidden, by the way)

Comment: It's like `if(document.forms.length > 1)document.forms[1].submit();`. Yes, it's the second form. No, the other form is not submitting, and does not share the same action.

Comment: ok, fair enough - I take it that code runs as a result of some sort of user action, or, if not, it's definitely run after the form is loaded into the DOM?

Comment: I use PHP to generate the HTML, so I can database the `uniqid('pid_', true)`, which I viewed in source code to look just like the example above (spare the sensitive data).

Comment: and you've checked what is being sent to paypal is as you expect? i.e. developer tools network tab

Comment: Do you get an apprroval url or something like that from paypal before generating your page?

Comment: `@Jaramoda X`, is this format okay?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after further investigation. `item_name_`*x* format requires

```
<input name='upload' type='hidden' value='1' />
```

Oh, I also left out the `quantity_`*x*, but changed that, as well.

Unfortunately, this was not really what I wanted, since this is a 3rd Party Shopping Cart solution. I was really wanting to continually submit PayPal Buy Now Buttons, but that did not work, since Browsers usually only submit once per form action. PayPal should not be forcing us to use their Express Checkout API to do what should be simple; submitting multiple items to the 1st Party Shopping Cart. PayPal should be devalued by the SEC, for this.

Comment: I'd suggest you to construct the form into a url and do a url redirect, instead of doing a form submit.. This is because when an invalid URL query parameter is passed, PayPal apparently ignores it.. This may not be applicable now that you have solved the issue but take it as a tip for future errors..